# Redirect output from ENTRYPOINT bash script to console

Tags: bash, docker

I have the following bash script that is run as the `ENTRYPOINT` in my Dockerfile:

```
#!/bin/bash
python main.py
./bin/localstack start --host
```

When i start the container for this image, i receive the output from the python command:

```
localstack         |  * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
localstack         |  * Environment: production
localstack         |    WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
localstack         |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
localstack         |  * Debug mode: on
localstack         |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
localstack         |  * Restarting with stat
localstack         |  * Debugger is active!
localstack         |  * Debugger PIN: 177-561-621
```

But i do not see the output of the localstack start command, nor does the command get executed. If i attach a shell to the container, and execute `./bin/localstack start --host` manually from the working directory, the command both executes and shows the output.

How do I run the command successfully, and redirect the output to the same shell that already serves as output for the python command?

Comment: Does main.py exit to let the script continue?

Comment: main.py does not exit, it's process is kept alive after it starts. Does this prevent the next command in the bash script from being executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I simply had to chain the two processes the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
python main.py & ./bin/localstack start --host
```